# Yammer Feed App URL

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, yammer

[image] After adding the yammer app part it defaults to a specific address. Can this be changed? Am I missing something on the Central Admin side?

Comment: the url mentioned in error, is it valid and is it part of any AAM settings?\

Comment: the end of it is the app domain I configured..apps.uff.ufl.edu I'm actually getting this same path on any app I add via the store and AAM.  So this must be more of a configuration in the Service applications or something.